# How To Set Prompt Depending Of The Exit Code Of Previous Command In zsh?

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

I Want If The Previous succeeded

```
PROMPT="%F{46}(^v^)%f %F{67}%n%f%F{61}@%f%F{70}%m%f %F{116}in %f%F{65}%~%f%B%F{39} ->%f%b "
```

If Not

```
PROMPT="%F{9}(\`O´)%f %F{67}%n%f%F{61}@%f%F{70}%m%f %F{116}in %f%F{65}%~%f%B%F{39} ->%f%b "
```

Answer (score 2):

`zsh` has a conditional escape available to use in prompts. It has the general form

```
%(x.true.false)
```

where `x` is a single character condition to test, and `true` and `false` are arbitrary strings that the `%(...)` construct will expand to when that condition is true or false, respectively. In your case, the condition character will be `?`, so you can write

```
PROMPT="%(?.%F{46}(^v^)%f.%F{9}(\`O´)%f) %F{67}..."
```